# ImportError: No module named 'jwt'

Tags: python, jwt

I installed pyjwt-1.7.1-py package thinking this error would go away.

But yet, i continue to get this

```
ImportError: No module named 'jwt'
```

I can see that there is a folder created C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\pkgs\pyjwt-1.7.1-py_0 and inside that there are two folders
jwt
PyJWT-1.7.1.dist-info

Both are not empty

I am trying to run a python program in PyCharm. Using python 3.5 as the interpreter.

Below is the image showing where the pyjwt is available
[image]

Comment: make sure you pycharm is using the env where you downloaded jwt

Comment: How did you install `pyjwt`?

Comment: I suggest you read up about package management with `conda`.

Comment: in pycharm in your project open FIle -> settings and check project interpreter, is your package installed in the list? if not you have to install it via the pycharm "+" plus button in this window

Comment: Add this package to current virtual environment in pycharm `File->New Project Settings -> Preferences for New Projects -> Project Interpreter`

Comment: To answer how i installed pyjwt, i ran -> conda install -c conda-forge pyjwt. I do pyjwt package under File->New Project Settings -> Preferences for New Projects -> Project Interpreter, edited the question to show that image

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

this will return the python path that you are actually using.
The most likely is that you have different python installations and they are nit matching.

Comment: *The most likely is that you have different python installations and they are nit matching.* Can you include in your answer how to fix that? Thanks!